# REST communication between spring boot applications

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I have 2 spring boot applications; appA and appB.

appB makes requests to appA via REST GET/POST etc...
I'd like to protect my appA so that it only responds to appB and maybe other apps in future.

Host of appB is not known so I cannot set.
`@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")`

I was thinking about using jwt with shared secret? But I don't know how to implement this...

Comment: https://medium.com/@darutk/oauth-access-token-implementation-30c2e8b90ff0                                     Go for it. Its simple and easy. Once you understand the concept see implementation here                                                                                                https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-implement-java-oauth-20-to-sign-in-with-git-1

Comment: the thing is that appB is a microservice part of a bigger application. It  is protected by keycloak so every request to appB must have auth header.
appA is running outside of this microservice arhitecture. it doesn't have access to keycloak. it must respond to only requests from appB)

Comment: Yes so you will be sending every information in request headers. What is the confusion?